# Spontaneous symmetry breaking of gauge symmetry in 1+1 dimensions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

The Mermin-Wagner theorem states that continuous global symmetries cannot be broken in two or fewer spacetime dimensions; however, I have not seen this statement applied to gauge theories. Does it apply; ie, is there a Higgs mechanism for 1+1 QFTs?

Comment: This question has already answered. Follow the link http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210488/higgs-mechanism-in-11-spacetime-dimensions. And links therein

Comment: Gauge "symmetry" is not a symmetry but rather a redundancy in how you describe a system. Thus, there is no conserved current associated with it nor can you "break" it. This is discussed in detail here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13870/gauge-symmetry-is-not-a-symmetry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauge symmetry is actually not spontaneously broken in the Higgs mechanism; this is a common misconception.  See [What role does "spontaneously symmetry breaking" played in the "Higgs Mechanism"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190416/what-role-does-spontaneously-symmetry-breaking-played-in-the-higgs-mechanism).  Therefore the Mermin-Wagner theorem does not apply to the Higgs mechanism, and the Higgs mechanism is possible in 1+1D.