# Why is 2nd-order time derivative crucial to Higgs/amplitude mode?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, lagrangian-formalism, higgs, bose-einstein-condensate

I read in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0610773) (page 11 first a few sentences) that 2nd-order time derivative in the action or the equation of dynamics is indispensable for the excitation of Higgs/amplitude mode. The paper provides no detail but mentions that Gross-Pitaevski theory as a 1st-order example without Higgs.

Why is this claim? It doesn't seem obvious to me from the standard derivation of the Higgs excitaion (e.g., in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/190684/20564) of Higgs mode). The spatial part remains the same. The temporal part becomes something like $$(\psi+\delta\psi)[\partial_0\delta\psi-iq(A_0+\frac{1}{q}\partial_0\theta)(\psi+\delta\psi)],$$ in which $\delta\psi$ and $\theta$ are the amplitude and phase fluctuations of $\psi$, respectively.

Comment: There is a nice explanation in the review by Pekker and Varma: https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2968, especially Section II (page 8). The point is that the linear time derivative couples the amplitude and phase/Goldstones to each other, so there isn't a distinct amplitude mode.